# Is there an easy way to update connection strings to a database moved to a different instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, connections

I have created a new instance of SQL Server 2008 r2 and exported my database to the new instance.  Then I realized that the connection string for all of my datasets still point to the original database.  Is there an easy way to update the connection string for each of the datasets?

This also brings a question on deployment.  Each customer that purchases the software would have a different connection string.  Can you point me to some documentation that would explain how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is just a *query language* used by all relational DBMS.

Comment: which DB you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008r2. I am programming in C# with Visual Studio 2013.  Sorry for the lack of info, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: This is an overall design decision to me, and just an opinion. How you configure or point your application to any database instance can be done various ways. I have seen it done a few different ways but doesn't mean it is an acceptable answer over what someone else may have seen or done.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to update the connection string for each of the datasets?

Connection strings are what client software use to figure out how to connect to the data store. So I would say outside of a programmatic update (search and replace) no there is no straightforward or native way to do this.

> Each customer that purchases the software would have a different connection string. Can you point me to some documentation that would explain how to handle this scenario?

This is really more of a question of *software install/deployment/configuration*, but typically setting the connection string would be done through the installation process.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  it actually helps with my thought process.

Answer (score 0):

## Directory Service

One way to deliver a connection string is through a [directory service](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) such as [LDAP](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP).

If every human and app looks up the connection string in the directory service, then you have only one place to update when a change happens.

Programming environments often provide access to directory services. For example, Java offers [JNDI](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface).